# Under what conditions can we swap a limit with an infinite product?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

When is the following true: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{nk} = \prod^{\infty}_{k=1}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{nk}$$

Comment: Hint: This can be rewritten as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^m a_{nk} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^m \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{nk}$$ So, you are swapping the first two limits, then you are swapping the limit and the product. So, at the very least, the product of the limits must be defined. But, the question is really more when is this true: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^m a_{nk} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^m a_{nk}$$ You are probably looking at something like the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Assuming $a_{nk} > 0$ and the infinite products are nonzero, you can take logarithm of both sides and transform this to a question of interchanging limit with sum.  The standard cases are monotone convergence and dominated convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{nk} = \prod^{\infty}_{k=1}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{nk}$$

If and only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(\prod^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{nk}) = \log(\prod^{\infty}_{k=1}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{nk})$$ (Warning see footnote below <sup>1</sup>)

Since $\log$ takes product to sum by setting $b_{nk}=\log(a_{nk})$ the above is equivalent to whether
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_{nk} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{nk}$$

Now you can use the [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) which in this setting says:

If $|b_{nk}|\leq c_k$ for a sequence $c_k$ for which $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k$ exists and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{nk} = b_k$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ exists and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_{nk} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_{k}$$

Translated back to products, you need that $|a_{nk}|\leq c_k$ for a sequence such that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty c_k$ exists then if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{nk} = a_k$ then $\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ exists and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{nk} = \prod^{\infty}_{k=1}a_{k}$$

---

<sup>1</sup> This approach only works if the $a_{nk}$ are positive. Otherwise you can't take $\log$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true.. if you have $a_{nk} = 0.5$ for instance, then $b_{nk} = -\ln(2)$ and the minimum value of $c_k$ for the sum is $\ln(2)$, but the sum of $c_k$ diverges, yet the infinite product exists with and without the limit interchange.