# Dominated convergence for infinite product proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Dominated convergence theorem for an infinite product states that:

$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \prod_{k=1}^{∞}(a_{kn}+1)=\prod_{k=1}^{∞}\lim_{n \to ∞} (a_{kn}+1)$$ 
If :
There exists a convergent sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$$ such that (for all k)$$b_{k}{\ge}|a_{nk}|$$

My question is : Why is the above theorem true ? (I think it has something to do with using the dominated convergence theorem  for infinite 
sums but I don’t know how.)

Comment: To convert a product into a sum, take the logarithm. Some care is required to verify that that's legitimate, you may need to split the product at some $k_0$ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: first recall that the logarithm is a continuos function in its natural domain of definition. Thus, the logarithm of a limit is the limit of the logarithm. Now use this fact together with the well known property:
$$\ln(ab)=\ln(a) + \ln(b)$$
($a,b>0$), which can be easily extended to infinite products.

EDIT: suppose $a_{nk} >0$ (otherwise, you will just need to change signs). Then, the logarithm is positive and you get:
$$e^{b_k} -1 \geq a_{nk}$$
Thus, you have found
$$c_k := e^{b_k} - 1$$
which is you what you were looking for.
You can proceed similarly for the other cases.

EDIT: You could proceed as in [Under what conditions can we swap a limit with an infinite product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167317/under-what-conditions-can-we-swap-a-limit-with-an-infinite-product). If you assume that the absolute value of the logarithm is bounded, you have concluded.

EDIT: I will rephrase the proof of the link above, applying it to your case. Suppose that there exist $c_k$ such that
$$ |\ln(a_{nk} + 1)| \leq c_k $$
with $\sum_{k} c_k$ convergent. Then, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem for series we have:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k} \ln(a_{nk} +1) = \sum_{k} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(a_{ nk} +1) $$
Notice that the inequality for the logarithm implies the following (let $d_{nk}:= a_{nk} + 1 > 0$):
$$ |d_{ nk}| \leq e^{c_k} $$
But then:
$$ \prod_{k} e^{c_k} = e^{\sum_{k} c_k} $$
is convergent. Moreover, you can easily see that you can interchange limit and infinite product by the equation above involving the sums of logarithms. Thus, when there is a bound $c_k$ as above for the logarithms, the dominated convergence theorem also holds for infinite products.

Comment: The above result is usually considered with $a_{ nk}+1 >0$. Clearly, if instead all these elements were negative, you could just consider the result with $-(a_{ nk}+1)>0$ from which you would conclude. If some of them are positive and some negative, you may try to consider which is the sign of the result: for instance, if $a,b <0$, $ab>0$, so you may instead deal with $(-a)(-b)$ without problems.

Comment: You have to consider $a_{nk} +1 <0$, not just $a_{nk}$: if $-1 < a_{nk} \leq 0$, you have no problems with the logarithm

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: If $-1 < a_{nk} \leq 0$, then $|\ln(a_{nk} +1)|=-\ln(a_{nk}+1)$, so the inequality needs to be modified a bit. Can you see how?

Comment: You know that $-\ln(a_{nk}+1) \geq 0$ by definition of absolute value, so you obtain $-1< a_{nk} \leq 0$ as said above. But then, you have found an upper bound for $|a_{nk}|$ in such cases, namely $1$. Thus, you have that $c_k=1$.

Comment: shouldn't $ c_{k} = -exp(-b_{k}) +1 $ for negative case

Comment: Due to the minus sign, that would be a lower bound, and not an upper bound (because $\geq$ would be turned into $\leq$).

Comment: $ b_{k} {\ge} | ln(a_{nk} +1)| $ <br> $ b_{k} {\ge}  -ln(a_{nk} +1) $ <br> $ -b_{k} {\le}  ln(a_{nk} +1) $ <br> $exp(-b_{k}) -1 {\le} a_{nk} $<br> $-exp(b_{k})+1 {\ge} |a_{nk}|$

Comment: Yes, this is correct (but you have to write $- exp(-b_k) + 1$). I forgot about the convergence of the series, so my previous bound was not useful for your question.

Comment: How will convergence of the series $ c_{k} $ imply convergence of Series $b_{k}$

Comment: You have to check it. Also use the fact that you are assuming the series with $b_k$ convergent by the series version of the dominated convergence Theorem

Comment: Try to see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496715/infinite-product-with-sign-changes.

Comment: This is not my question to using  dominated convergence on the log we will need to find a *convergent* series with terms $b_{k} {\ge} ln(a_{k}+1)$ it has been shown that finding a *convergent* series $c_{k} {\ge} |a_{k}|$ is enough by using the inequalities but we still have to show that if the series with terms $c_{k}$  is *convergent*  then that will imply $b_{k}$ will be convergent as the theorem requires $ c_{k} $ to be convergent

Comment: So dont we still need to show that if the convergent series with terms $c_{k}{\ge}|a_{nk}|$ will mean that the series with terms $ b_{k}{\ge} ln(a_{nk}+1)$ will also be convergent because that is needed for dominated convergence for an infinte sum

Comment: You assume that the series with logarithm is convergent, which implies that the product is itself convergent. To conclude with your result, you can try to prove that even the series with $c_k$ is convergent (use the fact that the series with $b_k$ is).

Comment: Is the statement of my  second edit correct and what is the answer to the question in my second edit ?

Comment: Is the statement in my second  edit correct?

Comment: Yes, but if instead you suppose that $c_k$ exists, everything else will follow, as said in my edit and in the link.

Comment: What is meaning of suppose that $c_{k}$ exists

Comment: can you please give me a full proof

Comment: Suppose that some $c_k$ exists and it is an upper bound for the absolute value of $a_{nk}$, and the series of $c_k$ converges. Then, by the previous discussion, you can conclude that you can interchange limit and product.

Comment: Can you please combine all ideas into one proof

Comment: If you assume $c_{k}{\ge}|a_{k}|$ exists and is convergence then how exactly will convergence of series $b_{k}{\ge}|ln(a_{nk})|$ follow

Comment: I think the above comment needs to be proved also

Comment: I have written a more detailed proof, following the link of the previous edit